# how will webserver running IIS 5.0 handle multiple dbserver connections?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008, iis-5

one websevers one website one page,

three users clients

two dbservers different databases on each using sql server 2005 server express

when any of the client accessing the page from his computer clicks on

```
button A ---- connect to 'table1' of db 'first' on dbserver1
button B ---- connect to 'table1' of db 'second' on dbsever2
```

question is in my experience with vs08 coding, when one connection is opened, another attempt to open an connection is refused, saying an connection is already there which needs to be closed first.

so how will the webserver IIS 5.0 handle this,  allow a connection at a time?

i think my question is not clear

for answerers:--

yes sql server allows multiple connections

but there are two sql servers running on two different computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sql server should easily allow multiple connections without issue.  It has nothing to do with IIS

Comment: please see the editted, its not one sql server.

for answerers:--

yes sql server allows multiple connections

but there are two sql servers running o two different computers.

Comment: and you can still open multiple connections to each of them, there is no problem there. You'll just need to use a different SqlConnection object for each seperate connection you want. baring in mind, each user is seperated by request. So if you need one connection to each database per user, that'll up to two different SqlConnection objects per request.